# Function doesn't work in browser and android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have code what should detect mobile devices and do my code, if it mobile device (below regex) which contain cookie check and if it absent popup div with buttons which gives cookie when clicked. 
But in mobile browser (android) and firefox when i click on button which should give cookie and hide div NOTHING HAPPENS. But in jsfiddle function which hide div works fine, in browser on my site - no. Yep i have jquery included in my page. I'm dissapointed, please help. I'm new in JS and sorry for my english

Function for hide div

> ```
>   hide_ask_div = function(){
>       $('#ask-user').hide();
> ```
>
> }

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqqu97av/1/) with mobile devices check 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj8yqkcz/) with no mobile devices check, just for test

Comment: `getCookie` is not defined, so your script blows up there.

Comment: It's defined with gettext.js, here is [link](http://pastebin.com/epsuDU9s)

Comment: Your `mobile` and `no_mobile` functions were undefined. Changing them from `function mobile()` to `mobile = function ()` fixed that problem and allowed the cookies to be set. I am still getting undefined errors, and can't test anything else without them being fixed, so hopefully this will work for you where you have all the libraries behind this.

Comment: @quantumwannabe Thanks you! It helped. Cookies sets fine, but hide_ask_div still don't work :(

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post a JSFiddle or Plunker with all the dependencies added.

Comment: @quantumwannabe sure, 1 min

Comment: [Jsfiddle with dependencies added](http://jsfiddle.net/e5s9uu7a/)

Comment: I don't see any dependencies, and am getting `Utf8 is not defined`, on this line `if(hit&&hit.length>2) return Utf8.decode(unescape(replaceAll(hit[2],'+','%20')));` Could you please add that dependency and any other

Comment: @quantumwannabe oh sorry. Here is it with gettext.js and kusaba.js which contain UTF8 var [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e5s9uu7a/3/)

Comment: I still can not access all of your dependencies, as kusaba.js references several php files, but I can confirm that `hide_ask_div` worked for me. Hopefully you can find a solution to your problem.